# Searching Docx files in java

Tags: java, jar, docx, searching-xml

I am writing an application for searching the **Content of Documents**
i have already written the code for searching the documents which are editable by notepad.

I also wish to do the same for docx files. After some research i have come up with these two things

1. http://www.infoq.com/articles/cracking-office-2007-with-java 
   this method requires me to extract docx file and then search the xml files however this would involve an extra overhead on the extraction part and frankly i dont know how to process an xml file ( discarding attribute content etc)
2. http://www.javadocx.com/download 
   this method allows me to import a jar library to my project and supposedly i can create docx files with it, what i dont understand is how to open docx files using it

can anyone recommend me a alternate method to perform the same action or help with the above two mentioned methods?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://tika.apache.org/ or docx4j or POI.